# Android Image Issue

Tags: android, image, listview

In my application, Listview contain one image. Onclick of this image change the image to another.I can identify which image is clicked and  assign new image  to it.
it will not change the image, after reloading it working fine .
how can i change the image without reloading ?

my program section will show the value of status_id returns 0 or 1

```
holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
    String s;
    Integer status_id;
    s =Integer.toString(position);
    holder.favorite.setImageResource(0); 
    status_id = change_status_of_Favorite(ChannelId[position],ChannelFavo[position]);
    if(status_id==0)
    {
        ChannelFavo[position] ="false";
        holder.favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_gray);
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Removed from Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
         ChannelFavo[position] ="true";
         holder.favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_icon);
         Toast.makeText(activity, "Added to Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //Toast.makeText(activity, "Position : "+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: can you check out for toggle button on android,i think it will help you

Comment: I tried with toggle button but still i am not able to change the image only the text of the toggle button is changing

Comment: do want to change the image background onlclick of the list item?then need to check for  onOptionsItemSelected then you will have the position of the list

Answer (score 0):

Ok,if want to do with the toggle button the please check my code
    Make new xml in res/drawable/imagefile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"
 encoding="UTF-8"?> <selector
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/off"
 /> <!-- default --> <item
 android:state_checked="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/on" />
<!-- pressed --> <item
      android:state_checked="false"
             android:drawable="@drawable/off" />
      <!-- unchecked --> </selector>
```

Now make the toggle button in you layour xml

```
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:background="@drawable/imagefile"
   />
```

In side you activity flashOnOff.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.off);
              or flashOnOff.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.on);
   you can also set the status using the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29 but just need to make new boolean varible to maintain the on/off
   I hope this will help you.

thank you.

Comment: I tried with your xml and setBackgroundResource() method it also not refresh the image (background image). When i scroll the listview then the image is changing mycode is append with my question